# how to switch display hardware devices?

Tags: c#, node.js

Sir, I have 3 display hardware devices which is used to display different content, how shall my program command which content display in which display hardware device? c# or nodejs/appjs

thanks very much! for any help!

~Rosone

Comment: What kind of "display hardware device" are we talking about? Actual displays? Smartwatches? C# or Node.js are very different things, is your app written in both somehow? Is your actual question just how run your program on a specific monitor?

Comment: actual display hardware device monitor. I know c# and nodejs are different. I'm evaluating if both of them I can use to select what content will be displayed in different monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I find something useful I think:

```
var myScreen = Screen.FromControl(originalForm);
var otherScreen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Equals(myScreen)) 
           ?? myScreen;
otherForm.Left = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Left + 120;
otherForm.Top = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Top + 120;

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;

    Application.Run(f);
}
```

but I'm not sure if nodejs would do this feature.